# Decoding/Encoding an array of mixed objects from JSON data

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm having trouble implementing the proper way of parsing the incoming `JSON` data into codeable objects because of an array which has mixed objects and I'm unable to figure out how to parse that array into an array with their respective object types.

I tried following the suggestion from here, since it seems to be similar but with no luck.
[Reddit link to tried solution.](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/812dbs/json_array_of_mixed_types_jsondecoder/)

I also red this article, and the ones it references.
[Article link.](https://medium.com/tsengineering/swift-4-0-codable-decoding-subclasses-inherited-classes-heterogeneous-arrays-ee3e180eb556)

But I'm just very confused what thing I have to exactly implement due to my inexperience with `swift` and being a newcomer to it.

Using dummy data, my incoming `JSON` data looks like [this.](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7bfe2a8fd1b84204b9580e3ab4386d5a)

My `Swift` model also contains several nested structs, but I don't have a problem with those, so I will only paste the relevant bits. But basically it looks like this:

```swift
struct Message: Codable {
    let messageID: Int
    let appVersion: String
    let certaintyFactor: Int
    let comments: String?
    let defaultPriority: String
    let explanation: [Explanation]
    let name: String
    let patient: [PatientInfo]
    let risk: String
    let rule: Rule
    let urgency: String

struct Explanation: Codable {
    let id, name: String
    let content: Resource

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case content
    }
}
```

And the models for the objects which a 'Resource' could be

```swift
struct Patient: Codable{
    let id: String
    let text: Text
    let identifier: [Identifier]
    let active: Bool
    let name: [Name]
    let telecom: [Identifier]
    let gender, birthDate: String
    let deceasedBoolean: Bool
    let address: [Address]
    let maritalStatus: MaritalStatus
    let multipleBirthBoolean: Bool
    let contact: [Contact]
    let communication: [Communication]
    let managingOrganization: ManagingOrganization

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case identifier
        case active
        case name
        case telecom
        case gender
        case birthDate
        case deceasedBoolean
        case address
        case maritalStatus
        case multipleBirthBoolean
        case contact
        case communication
        case managingOrganization
    }

}

struct Address: Codable {
    let use: String
    let line: [String]
    let city, postalCode, country: String
}

struct Communication: Codable {
    let language: MaritalStatus
    let preferred: Bool
}

struct MaritalStatus: Codable {
    let coding: [MaritalStatusCoding]
    let text: String
}

struct MaritalStatusCoding: Codable {
    let system: String
    let code, display: String
}

struct Contact: Codable {
    let relationship: [Relationship]
    let name: Name
    let telecom: [Identifier]
}

struct Name: Codable {
    let use, family: String
    let given: [String]
    let suffix: [String]?
}

struct Relationship: Codable {
    let coding: [RelationshipCoding]
}

struct RelationshipCoding: Codable {
    let system: String
    let code: String
}

struct ManagingOrganization: Codable {
    let reference, display: String
}
```

```
struct MedicationRequest: Codable {
    let resourceType, id: String
    let text: Text
    let contained: [Contained]
    let identifier: [Identifier]
    let status, intent: String
    let medicationReference: MedicationReference
    let subject, context: Context
    let authoredOn: String
    let requester: Requester
    let dosageInstruction: [DosageInstruction]
    let dispenseRequest: DispenseRequest
    let substitution: Substitution

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case resourceType
        case id
        case text
        case contained
        case identifier
        case status
        case intent
        case medicationReference
        case subject
        case context
        case authoredOn
        case requester
        case dosageInstruction
        case dispenseRequest
        case substitution
    }
}

struct Contained: Codable {
    let resourceType, id: String
    let code: Reason
}

struct Reason: Codable {
    let coding: [Coding]
}

struct Coding: Codable {
    let system: String
    let code, display: String
    let type: String?
}

struct Context: Codable {
    let reference, display: String
}

struct DispenseRequest: Codable {
    let validityPeriod: Period
    let numberOfRepeatsAllowed: Int
    let quantity, expectedSupplyDuration: ExpectedSupplyDuration
}

struct ExpectedSupplyDuration: Codable {
    let value: Int
    let unit: String
    let system: String
    let code: String
}

struct Period: Codable {
    let start, end: String
}

struct DosageInstruction: Codable {
    let sequence: Int
    let text: String
    let additionalInstruction: [Reason]
    let timing: Timing
    let asNeededCodeableConcept, route: Reason
    let doseQuantity, maxDosePerAdministration: ExpectedSupplyDuration
}

struct Timing: Codable {
    let timingRepeat: Repeat

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timingRepeat = "repeat"
    }
}

struct Repeat: Codable {
    let boundsPeriod: Period
    let frequency, period, periodMax: Int
    let periodUnit: String
}

struct MedicationReference: Codable {
    let reference: String
}

struct Requester: Codable {
    let agent: Context
    let onBehalfOf: MedicationReference
}

struct Substitution: Codable {
    let allowed: Bool
    let reason: Reason
}

//// MARK: - Text
struct Text: Codable {
    let status, div: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status,div
    }
}

// MARK: - Identifier
struct Identifier: Codable {
    let use: String
    let system: String
    let value: String
}
```

The parsing part

```swift
let jsonData = try? JSON(parseJSON: rowData).rawData()
let message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: jsonData!)
```

And finally my tested solution which I'm not able to get working because I don't know how to exactly write the encoder. 
I'm trying to follow a similar example, explained [here](https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/01/23/codable-enums/)

```swift
enum Resource{
    case patient(Patient)
    case medicationRequest(MedicationRequest)
}

extension Resource :Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case patient
        case medicationRequest
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            let leftValue =  try container.decode(Patient.self, forKey: .patient)
            self = .patient(leftValue)
        } catch {
            let rightValue =  try container.decode(MedicationRequest.self, forKey: .medicationRequest)
            self = .medicationRequest(rightValue)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case .patient(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .patient)
        case .medicationRequest(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .medicationRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `let jsonData = try? JSON(parseJSON: rowData).rawData(); let message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: jsonData!)` Why not directly `let message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: rowData)`? Also, don't write `try?`, write `do { let message = try JSONDecoder()... } catch { print("Ooops, error: \(error)")}`. Read errors they could have plenty of informations.

Comment: Thanks, @Larme it did produce a helpful error, but i'm not sure which struct's codingkeys it's missing.

`error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "medicationRequest", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "explanation", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"medicationRequest\", intValue: nil) (\"medicationRequest\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: I added codingkeys to Patient, MedicationRequest & Message just to be sure, but  to me it looks like it's having issue with the explanation struct?

Comment: The location of the missing key is very clear. Please learn to understand DecodingErrors, they are pretty easy to read. Look at the CodingKeys in `codingPath`: `explanation[0].content.medicationRequest`, that’s the key path.

Comment: One thing I noticed that jsonResponse of explanation key holds an array of dictionary but, both dictionaries should have the same set of key and different value pairs. But it's not. so you can't be able to decode it until it's same I hope it helps you.

Comment: @vadian I have no _idea_ which key it's missing. To me it looks like everything's there. Could you exactly state what I have to add, to at-least, satisfy the error?

Comment: In the JSON Editor on the right side there is the hierarchy, you can very easily navigate through the hierarchy. Open `explanation` then open the first item (`[0]`), then open `content`. You will see that there is no entry `medicationRequest` that's exactly what the error message tells you. If a key is missing declare the corresponding struct or struct member as optional (add `?`)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed that jsonResponse of explanation key holds an array of dictionary but, both dictionaries should have the same set of key and different value pairs. But it's not. so you can't be able to decode it until it's the same I hope it helps you.